# Typescript - assure that return of function is of given type

Tags: typescript

Having a simple function which accepts some variable, how can we let TS know that the output will ALWAYS satisfy the type of some variable and thus it shouldn't yell about

`Type 'string | Date' is not assignable to type`?

I.e.

```
const getStringOrDate(asString = true) => {
    if (asString) {
       return new Date().toLocaleDateString()
    } else {
        return new Date()
    }
  }


const today: Date = getStringOrDate(false);
^  Type 'string | Date' is not assignable to type Date
```

Comment: A better design would be to have two separate functions, like `getDate` and `getDateAsString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define the function multiple times with different types

and assign different return types, you define a return type by appending it after the brackets, for example `let fn = (): number => 1;`

using this you can just use this

```
function getStringOrDate(asString?: true = true): string;
function getStringOrDate(asString?: false = true): Date;
function getStringOrDate(asString = true): Date | string {
    return asString ? new Date().toLocaleString() : new Date();
}
```

Note that this only works with the function keyword, not es5 arrow functions

this would set the return type to string or Date correctly

Answer (score 0):

Besides multiple function implementation (which should be preferred), you could also use a conditional return type, it looks like this:

```js
function getStringOrDate<T extends boolean = true>(
  asString = true as T
): T extends true | undefined ? string : Date {
  return (asString ? new Date().toLocaleDateString() : new Date()) as any;
}
```

the downside of this method is the need to use casting, however implementations of this kind may be more idiomatic very specific cases.